# Avoid `undefined` when using `TypeError` in type-class constraint

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, undefined, typeclass

I have a type-class instance like this:

```hs
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (TypeError ( 'Text "Some error")) => SomeClass x where
  someMethod = undefined
```

This instance exists at the end of other (valid) instances. The idea is to have the compiler throw a type error when the user writes a type that doesn't adhere to these valid instances. `TypeError` in instance constraint achieves this, but this also forces me to fill in the method with `undefined`, which feels like a hack.

Is there a way to avoid this? Or do it better?

[Here's the real-world code](https://github.com/srid/ema/blob/4004647873e6572013c6fbb5017d820520e99e91/src/Data/SOP/Extra.hs#L34-L35) with this pattern.

Comment: I feel like there was a discussion about having a type class like that with a method that could be used in impossible situations, that's all the help I have at the moment.

Comment: From a "moral" point of view, this could be seen as a deficiency in GHC, not in your code. Since your instance will never be evaluated, then really there's no need to ask for an instance at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could achieve is this. Essentially, I defined a `TypeErr` type family standing for both the standard `TypeError` constraint and an additional `Impossible` constraint providing the needed witness. `Impossible` would always fail to resolve as a constraint, but the type error is triggered first anyway.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, UndecidableInstances, TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.TypeLits (
  ErrorMessage (Text),
  TypeError,
 )

class Impossible where
  impossible :: a

type family TypeErr t where
  TypeErr t = (TypeError t, Impossible)

-- Dummy example
class SomeClass x where
  someMethod :: x -> Maybe x

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (TypeErr ( 'Text "Some error")) 
         => SomeClass x where
  someMethod = impossible

main :: IO ()
main = print (someMethod True)
{-
<source>:19:15: error:
    * Some error
    * In the first argument of `print', namely `(someMethod True)'
      In the expression: print (someMethod True)
      In an equation for `main': main = print (someMethod True)
-}
```

Comment: [I like it!](https://github.com/srid/ema/pull/81/commits/98deb1dc90ae4621bd451e18c3289700a890fdb4)

Answer (score 2):

We have the [`Disallowed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trivial-constraint-0.7.0.0/docs/Data-Constraint-Trivial.html#t:Disallowed) class in the `trivial-constraint` package. It offers the [`nope`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trivial-constraint-0.7.0.0/docs/Data-Constraint-Trivial.html#v:nope) pseudo-method, which is a version of `undefined` that can only be used in impossible contexts (and witnesses this by being possible to “use” *unboxed*, which you can't do with standard `undefined`).

```
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Disallowed "fallback for `SomeClass`")
    => SomeClass x where
  someMethod = nope
```